# How can i decode this base64 array

Tags: base64

Can you please help me decode this base64 array

CNa1yQEIjrbJAQiYtskBCKK2yQEIp7bJAQiptskBCLmDygE=

Someone already decoded this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183575/what-is-following-header-for-x-chrome-variations), i just want to know how he did this.

i already tried base64_decode() but i got something like ÖµÉ¶É¶É¢¶É§¶É©¶É¹Ê

From what Arsen says in his thead, its a base64 encoded 35 bit array,

Thank you.

Comment: i already tried base64_decode() i got somthing like ÖµÉŽ¶É˜¶É¢¶É§¶É©¶É¹ƒÊ

Comment: That's right. Nothing says that what you get by decoding has to make sense to *you* — the purpose of that question was precisely to make sense of it. By the way, it's 35 bytes, not bits, there was a typo in that question.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use `base64_decode`. Also you can decode it with some online tool (like [this](http://s12v.github.io/hasher/) in `encode` tab).
Using PHP I get this output: `ÖµÉŽ¶É˜¶É¢¶É§¶É©¶É¹ƒÊ`