# What is the HTTP_X_CLIENT_DATA in the $_SERVER array?

Tags: php, google-chrome, http-headers

I see an element in the `$_SERVER` array called `HTTP_X_CLIENT_DATA` - `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLIENT_DATA']`, and its value looks like some kind of base64-encoded string. What is this element used for?

Here is an example value, which I tried decoding but seems to be also encrypted?

> CJa2yQEIprbJAQjBtskBCPqcygEIqZ3KAQ==

Comment: How can you see it in `$_SERVER` if Chrome is only sending this to Google-owned domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be both uncommon and non-standard. Here's a [List of HTTP Header Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

If you provide the URL that served it, we might able to help you further.

Answer (score 10):

Google Chrome passes the X-Client-Data request header to randomly assign field trials of various features to users, as [documented here](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html).

It looks like it used to be called X-Chrome-Variations - see [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13239916/436776) which gives a broad overview.

To prevent Chrome sending the header when fetching your page, open your page in an Incognito Window instead.

I think the value is a base64 encoded protobuf - paste the value into the second textarea on [this page](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) and click the base64 button to decode.

For current list of Google owned domains it is sent to, see https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/google/core/common/google_util.cc?q=IsGoogleAssociatedDomainUrl

Answer (score 8):

It's a header with a unique identifier which signifies your specific chrome profile on your specific chrome installation.   Google says they use it for simple A/B testing but it seems to be a rather unique identifier if all they need is a few feature flags.

This is really just another way that Google is tracking individuals activity (spying) across a wide spectrum of their products.